# Loopback 4: Test problems with Sinon and injections

Tags: sinon, strongloop, loopback4

We have trying to do a test with loopback. The test involve to call the google API and we want to mock it with Sinon.

**The Controller:**

[...]

In the constructor:

```
  @inject('services.OAuth2Service')
    private oauth2Service: OAuth2Service
```

[...]

In the endpoint:

```
@post('/user-accounts/authenticate/oauth2', {
async authenticateOauth2(
    @requestBody() oauthRequest: OAuthId,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) _req: Request,
  ): Promise<AccessToken> {
    const email = await this.oauth2Service.getOAuth2User(oauthRequest); // The method to mock.
  ....
}
```

**The test:**

```
it('oauth2 authentication with google', async () => {

 //Create a spy for the getOAuth2User function
    inject.getter('services.OAuth2Service');
    var oauth2Service: OAuth2Service;

    var setOauthSpy = sinon.spy(oauth2Service, "getOAuth2User"); // Error: Variable 'oauth2Service' is used before being assigned

    const res = await client
      .post('/user-accounts/authenticate/oauth2')
      .set('urlTenant', TEST_TENANT_URL1A)
      .set('userType', TEST_USERTYPE1)
      .send({
        code: TEST_GOOGLE_AUTH2_CODE_KO,
        providerId: TEST_GOOGLE_PROVIDER,
        redirectUri: TEST_GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
      })
      .expect(401);
    expect(res.body.error.message).to.equal('The credentials are not correct.');

    setOauthSpy.restore();

  });
```

How can we test this method? how can we test an endpoint who involves an injection in the constructor in loopback? Please, we need any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Before running the test, create a [loopback context](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Context.html), bind your stub to `"services.OAuth2Service"` and use that context to create the controller you want to test.
2. default value (probably not what you want)

In the place where you use `@inject`, you provide a default value (and possibly [indicate the dependency is optional](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Dependency-injection.html#optional-dependencies)), e.g. like this:

```js
@inject('services.OAuth2Service', { optional: true })
    private oauth2Service: OAuth2Service = mockOAuth2Service,
```

In other places this might come handy for you, but you should probably not pollute your default production code with defaults to test objects.

Comment: Thanks, I wii try it.